# It is possible to run commands from Gradle/Android Studio in similar way Maven/IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, intellij-idea

My question is associate to the possibility to run (one or more) commands from  Android Studio aiming to compile project (and dependencies) such as Maven.

In general, I would like know how can I run command line such as `$ gradle myapp-project`

In this case, I would like click or deploy my application without compile it again. So, this is a important requirement because if it is not possible, the build and deploy process could be very slow.

Comment: Which version of Android Studio are you using? If you're on 2.0 beta 7 (http://tools.android.com/download/studio/beta) you can just click on the run button. It only compiles if there are any changes and then deploys to your device. Optionally you can use Build -> "Build APK" to only build the apk

Comment: Thank you @NageshSusarla for reply my question. My intention about this question is identify if there is a mode to compile and build AS projects from command line.